# How to enable "Private Browsing" in Safari (Mac) and open a new link? Scripting Bridge

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, safari, scripting-bridge, incognito-mode

I'm currently trying to enable "Private Browsing" in Safari for Mac, through `Scripting Bridge` but without any success. The following code shows how to do the same thing, but for Google Chrome (creating a new window with incognito mode enabled and opening a new link):

```
chromeBrowser = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.google.Chrome"];

ChromeWindow *window = [[[chromeBrowser classForScriptingClass:@"window"] alloc] initWithProperties:@{@"mode": @"incognito"}];
[chromeBrowser.windows addObject:window];

ChromeTab *tab = [window.tabs firstObject];
tab.URL = url;
[chromeBrowser activate];
```

But, unfortunately, Safari works a little different comparing to Chrome. Each Chrome's window works separately in terms of "private browsing" (incognito). In Safari, when you enable the the "private browsing", the whole application will reflect that option, not just a particular window. Any ideas on how to do that, using `Scripting Bridge` or something similar?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Safari's AppleScript dictionary doesn't give you access to Private Browsing mode, so there's no way to do it directly in Scripting Bridge.

You could do it with an NSAppleScript using System Events, like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set menuItemName to localized string "Private Browsing …"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    if menu item menuItemName of menu 1 of menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1 exists then
        click menu item menuItemName of menu 1 of menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1
        keystroke return
    else
        click menu item menuItemName of menu 1 of menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1
    end if
end tell
```

System Events scripting can't be done via Scripting Bridge, and it's slower and flakier than scripting an application directly, but it might be your best option. If you go this route, make sure your cross-scripting entitlement includes the bundle ID for the System Events application.

Comment: sorry for the late response. is that the only way of doing it? and another thing: that'll only work with the english translated Safari, other languages won't work. Is there any other way to press the Private Browsing item without knowing the language?

Comment: It's the only way I can think of. Scripting Bridge definitely won't work unless Apple updates the Safari AppleScript dictionary.

Comment: And I've updated the code in my answer to work with non-English systems.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the "localized string" part is not working if I'm not using Safari in English (btw, it's "Private Browsing..." not "Private Browsing ..."). Any ideas on how to get the localized string for every language?